# stick shared library to app

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, shared

Is it possible to stick a shared library to an app? I don't want to cross compile or anything like that. the shared library uses typical libraries which are available on target systems( i.e. Ubuntu 32bit x86) according to 'ldd'.

Comment: What do you mean by "sticking" the shared library to the app?

Comment: every possible way to make a shared library definitions accessible for app! let me explain that the reason I want to do this is to  avoid install a package on all client systems.

Comment: If I'm seeking for a stupid thing please tell me!

Comment: If there is a staticly built version of the library available (libxxx.a instead of libxxx.so), the easiest way would be to link against that. If that is not possible, you could create something like a self-extracting executable tar file with the app and the shared library. For example, see http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts

Comment: That was nearly exactly what I was looking for!but I can't mark a comment as an answer...

Comment: Okay then, added as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a staticly built version of the library available (libxxx.a instead of libxxx.so), the easiest way would be to link against that. If that is not possible, you could create something like a self-extracting executable tar file with the app and the shared library. For example, see http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts